# Changing a property of a button in VC2 when I have its title in VC1

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uibutton, xcode4.2, segue

I have two UIViewControllers: VC1 and VC2.
VC1 has a button that takes me to VC2 and VC2 has a few buttons with images.

In VC1 I have a list (queried from a sqlite db) of some of VC2 button titles.
I need to change the VC2 button images that match the titles from VC1.
In other word, When pressing the button to move from VC1 to VC2 I need the images to be changed only for the buttons listed in the result query from VC1.

Comment: better u pass the value to constructor .....

Comment: What do you mean ? I attached the buttons to a collection array of buttons, but the collection is initialized with the buttons only when the view appears so I'm not able to change the properties.

Comment: can u post a bit of code so that i can understand much better... or did u get the struggled...

Comment: Yes, I posted the code in the next answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following declarations in the VC2.h file:

```
@interface VC2 : UIViewController 
{
    NSArray *buttons;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;
@end
```

All the buttons in VC2 are related to the Collection.
In VC1 I'm using the prepareforsegue in the following way:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender  
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"VC1Segue"] == TRUE) 
    {
        [self getPictureNamesFromDB];
        VC2 *vc = [segue destinationViewController];     
        UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"XXXXX.png"];
        for(UIButton *button in vc.buttons) {
            [button setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the buttons Collection is being initialised only when I move to the next view and also I did not understand what you mean by passing throw the constructor...

Thank you

Comment: hi ...  [self getPictureNamesFromDB]; in this method your storing the buttons or images ? other question is the button count  fixed(say eg. 2, 3 like)?

Comment: Hi, the method getPictu.... returns the name of the pictures from a sqlite db. and the buttons have ids (set at storyboard)